# How to hide div if video source is empty via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If the src is empty like below I want to hide video_wrapper class

```
<div class="video_wrapper" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display: none;">
  <video id="df-video" playsinline="" webkit-playsinline="" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"> 
    <source  src="" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

I have tried the following jquery but its hiding also when src has any video format.

```
if ( jQuery('video[src][src=""]') )
   jQuery(".video_wrapper").hide();
else
   jQuery(".video_wrapper").show();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/v87b5feq/

Comment: You need to check the `.length` property of the jQuery collection. A jQuery collection itself (an object) is always a truthy value.

Comment: Maybe try something like this: `if ( $('#df-video > source:first').attr('src') )`.  It should evaluate as true if src contains a value and false if it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you are looking for `video` element that has a `source` element inside, where it's attribute's `src` is empty:

```
$('video source[src=""]')
```

Here is an example based on your code:

```js
$('video source[src=""]').each(function() {
  $(this).parents('.video_wrapper').hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="video_wrapper" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
  <video id="df-video" playsinline="" webkit-playsinline="" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"> 
    <source  src="" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>

<div class="video_wrapper" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
this will not be hidden
  <video id="df-video" playsinline="" webkit-playsinline="" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"> 
    <source  src="b" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```